# Is Ganon Supposed To Revive Himself?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I've been playing Zelda OOT on my N64 for a long while now, since I was around nine years old. It took me a while to first beat the game, and when I did, I discovered that I was able to beat the final boss, Ganondorf/Ganon over and over, and he/they would never permanently go away. I'm wondering if this is a feature of the game, and is supposed to happen, or if it's a bug and my cartridge is broken.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Like you couldn't finish the game, never saw the ending credits?

Comment: I see the ending credits, but then I can go back into the world and go into the boss room, and there he is again.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Perhaps the OP is referring to how once the game has been beaten and saved, it will revert to a point just before the final boss.

Comment: @Parzival Likely the game saves before that state and then goes back to that because it isn't really expecting that behaviour - it assumes once you beat it, you're done.

Comment: maybe, but I'm still going to wait for an answer, and I hate it when people downvote for no reason, whoever did, please explain why.

Comment: Downvoters don't have to explain themselves.  That happens just as part of downvoting: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is intended behavior - there is no "post ending" gameplay, so the final save sets you right at the beginning of the final dungeon with all the puzzles complete. Your options from this point are to either turn back and explore Hyrule - and obtain any heart pieces/equipment you may have missed, or go beat Ganon(dorf) again. Or start a new save.

This is fairly standard for adventure games of this sort, and even more so for the era in which it was released/developed.